Invisible HDRI and solid background
After going into the World tab and plugging in the sunrise.exr into the Environment texture in Nodes, it doesn't show up in the rendered view.
I have even checked the transparency. But this time I want the sunrise HDRI and instead of it, I see solid color background.



I'm guessing it is a single color because you have orthographic view turned on for your view.
For the viewport view, you can change it with the grid toggle in the N menu on the right (pointed at the arrow on the screenshot). You can also toggle it with Numpad 5 or use F3 to search for the Perspective / Orthographic toggle.

